# Looping multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I really can't get my head around on this multidimensional array, essentially I wanted to create a loop that will loop through all the array available in the **second level** (in this case is `[0],[1]` 2 times). Then for each loop it should return **each array on the second level** `[id][0]=16, [product_name][0]=Foot Spa, [price][0]=69.00`

```
Array 
(
[id] => Array 
( 
    [0] => 16 
    [1] => 17 
) 
[product_name] => Array 
( 
    [0] => Foot Spa
    [1] => Angelic Manicure 
) 
[price] => Array 
( 
    [0] => 69.00
    [1] => 42.00 
) 
)
```

I tried using multiple foreach loop but end up not able to stitch the values back since the loop were being separated individually.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['product_name'] as $eachProductName){
        echo $eachProductName;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to flip this around so it's like `array('id' => 16, 'product_name' => 'Foot Spa', 'price' => 69.00)`?

Comment: Please show the result you're trying to get, it's unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($inital_array as $key => $value)
{
 foreach($value as $vkey => $vvalue)
 {
   var_dump($key);
   var_dump($vkey);
   var_dump($vvalue);
   //or do sth else
 }
}
```

Thats how you can loop through the array, not sure how you want to use the values though....